# changing UITableView height according to super UIView height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a tableView which is inside a `UIView`. Auto layout is on and I'm changing the height constraint of super `UIView` programmatically. The height Of `UIView` change fine but TableView height doesn't change dependently.

This is how I have set the constraint of my `UITableView`:

[image]

I have set bottom and top constraint to `UIView`. So I expect when I change the height of `UIView`, my table view's height change but it's not.

I have also tried to change the frame of tableView but no difference.
And I need to mention that I'm doing that because I don't want my tableView to scroll.

How should I do that?

Comment: You might want to try `tableView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` to force the auto layout engine to redo its layout.

Comment: Give the top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to tableview to it's superview(i.e. UIView).

Comment: maybe also add `self.view.setNeedsLayout()` too?

Comment: @pbush25 after I call reloadData() method , then I call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize method but no difference.UIView's height changes but tableView doesn't

Comment: @MGP as you can see in my picture,I have set thoose

Comment: @Tj3n I have added setNeedsLayout too , But it doesn't work either

Comment: @sail there is a yellow arrow that says there is something missing in given constraints...I think tableview probably asking for height constraint...try to give height either to tableview or it's superview

Comment: @sali u can try add `self.yourTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` and see...sometimes your view dont resize is cause by some constraint that placed wrong

Answer (score 0):

It Seems like you have fixed the height of the tableview as well.Remove the height and width constraint of table view and pin all the edges of the table view to super view the problem will be gone.

Comment: No ,I haven't as you can see on my tableView constraint from the picture .